# What was the first story to depict a modern objective-based approach to artificial intelligence?

Tags: history-of, artificial-intelligence, science-fiction-genre

A great deal of older science fiction has a rules-based approach to artificial intelligence. Think Isaac Asimov's three laws of robotics: the robot has a set rule, and it follows it. In many such stories, intelligence arises, or is implied to arise, through highly complicated databases of rules. The basic idea is that a human takes a starting state and lists the explicit steps to get to their goal. Not coincidentally, this is much like how computers are programmed.

However, with modern models—of admittedly dubious intelligence, but nonetheless much more advanced than anything older authors could reference save human intelligence—primarily being based on optimizing an objective function, a different view of robots has emerged. A human sets a *goal*, and then the machine works backwards, until you have an incomprehensible list of mathematical operations with no apparent relevance to the goal, and that generally cannot be broken down into meaningful steps.

What was the first fictional story that explicitly mentioned an objective-function-based or mathematical optimization approach to artificial intelligence instead of a rules-based one?

Comment: I think some of this was already implicit in *Erewhon*, chapters 23 to 25 https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1906/pg1906-images.html#chap23 — although the topic is not primarily the intelligence of machines, but rather how they are not really so different from organic life in how they behave and evolve.

Comment: Ironically, I think ["The Evitable Conflict"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evitable_Conflict) may be an example of the sort of AI you're describing, unless you get more specific about exactly what qualifies as "objective-function-based AI."

Comment: @Kevin - It's not obligatory that every work by Isaac Asimov not be an example. The laws of robotics functioned differently in different stories by him.